# ImageButton is not centered in grid columns

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I added 3 buttons, and they're all in a grid but my `ImageButton` is not centered in my column :

Can anyone tell me the problem and how to fix it?

This is the xaml code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="Accounting.MainPage">

<StackLayout Margin="3">

    <Entry
        x:Name="NameEntry"
        Placeholder="Enter the Fullname"
        />
    <Grid Margin="3,-6,3,0">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button
            Margin="0,0,2,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            x:Name="AddButton"
            Text="Add"
            HeightRequest="50"
            BackgroundColor="#03A9F4"
            TextColor="White"
            CornerRadius="10"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Clicked="AddButton_Clicked"
            />
        <ImageButton
            Source="add.png"
            Grid.Column="2"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="50"
            HeightRequest="50"
            CornerRadius="50"
            />
        <Button
            Margin="2,0,0,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            x:Name="DeleteButton"
            Text="Delete"
            HeightRequest="50"
            BackgroundColor="#f44336"
            TextColor="White"
            CornerRadius="10"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Clicked="DeleteButton_Clicked"
            />

    </Grid>

    <ListView x:Name="WorkersListView" BackgroundColor="#ECEFF1" Margin="2" ItemSelected="WorkersListView_ItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding WorkerName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</StackLayout>
```

*Thanks for your help in advance*.

Comment: Post the full code so that we can help you better .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause:**

You set the Grid has three columns , but you set `Grid.Column` of **DeleteButton** equlas 3 .

**Solution:**

You can add a column of grid

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Or set the `Grid.Column` of `ImageButton` as 1 and `DeleteButton` as 2 .

Comment: It was a ridiculous problem :D , Thanks for your help, also i will ask my another problem in a new question page.